# Как с расширения GoogleChrome по нажатию на него отправить на мой сайт данные?

Tags: javascript, расширения

У меня есть расширение в нем подключен JS через background. По нажатию на расширение выполняется функция в JS файле.

Мне надо, чтобы пользователь с моим расширение, находясь на любом сайте, нажимая кнопку расширения отправлял на мой сайт ссылку того сайта, где он был. Могли бы вы показать как отправлять данные и как принимать данные на сайте, куда направится ссылка.


Пользователь->Нажимает на расширение-> Ссылка сайта на котором он находится отправляется на мой сайт -> Мой сайт принимает ссылку и выводит в консоль.